# Minimum sum of distances from sensor nodes to all others

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph

Is there a way to compute (accurate or hevristics) this problem on medium sized (up to 1000 nodes) weighted graph?

Place n (for example 5) sensors in nodes of the graph in such way that the sum of distances from every other node to the closest sensor will be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is called graph clustering. One of the popular methods to solve it is the Markov Cluster (MCL) Algorithm. A web search should provide some implementation examples. However it does not generally provide the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show that this problem is NP-hard by reduction from Vertex Cover.  This applies even if the graph is unweighted (you don't say whether it's weighted or not).

Given an unweighted graph G = (V, E) and an integer k, the question asked by Vertex Cover is "Does there exist a set of at most k vertices such that every edge has at least one endpoint in this set?"  We will build a new graph G' = (V', E), which is the same as G except that all isolated vertices have been discarded, solve your problem on G', and then use it to answer the original question about Vertex Cover.

Suppose there does exist such a set S of k vertices.  If we consider this set S to be the locations to put sensors in your problem, then every vertex in S has a distance of 0, and every other vertex is at a distance of exactly 1 away from a vertex that is in S (because if there was some vertex u for which this wasn't true, it would mean that none of u's neighbours are in S, so for each such neighbour u, the edge uv is not covered by the vertex cover, which would be a contradiction.)

Comment: I really appreciate theoretical statements, but to be honest, this is unlikely to answer the original question about a "way to compute (accurate or hevristics)".